# Error when using NDSolve Unable to find initian condition - beam bending

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, physics

please I have the following problem: I have a set of equations for the elasto-plastic response. I have decomposed the beam into two segments (the first segment is defined by coordinates [x1,y1] and [x2,y2] and the second segment is defined by [x1,y1] and [x2,y2].

Basically, the set of equations coming from kinematics and equilibrium forces, which I want to solve (numerically) is (I am interested only in the situation i = 1, 2, 3)

1. $ \dfrac{x_{i+1} + x_{i}}{l} - \cos \theta_i = 0$ (two equations to the system), $\theta_i$ is an angle in the i-th beam joint.
2. $ \dfrac{y_{i+1} + y_{i}}{l} - \sin \theta_i = 0$ (two equations to the system)
3. $ V_{Xi} - V_{Xi + 1} - F _{Xi} = 0 $ (Force equilibrium. $F_{Xi}$ denotes the external force and $V_{Xi}$ denotes the net force vector. An assumption is that there are not any forces $F$ or $V$ in the direction of x-axis.
4. $ V_{Yi} - V_{Yi + 1} - F _{Yi} = 0$ (An assumption is that there is not any force $F$ in the direction of y-axis. $V_{Yi}$ are being calculated so it is simplified to the relation $ V_{Yi} = V_{Yi + 1} $
5. $ M_{i} - M_{i+1} + (V_{Xi} - 1/2F_{Xi})*l*\sin \theta_{i} - (V_{Yi} - 1/2F_{Yi})*l*\cos \theta_{i} = 0$ (Balance of momentum - using the assumpetions, it can be simplified to the form: 5a) $ M_{i} - M_{i+1} - V_{Yi}*l*\cos \theta_{i} = 0$ (two equations to the system). $M_i$ is the bending moment at beam joint.
6. Response relation:
   $ \dot{M_{i}} = \lbrace 1 - H \left( M_i \dot{\kappa_i}\right) \left[ 1 + \tanh \left(\alpha H\left(1 - \left|\dfrac{M_i}{M_y}\right| \right) \left(\left|\dfrac{M_i}{M_y}\right| - 1\right)\right)\right]\rbrace EI \cdot \dot{\kappa_i}$ (one equation to the system - this response relation is valid only in the inner joints, which is in this case only i = 2). H denotes the Heaviside function, EI is the Young modulus, $\kappa$ is curvature, $\alpha$ is a coefficient, usually between 12 - 30 and $M_y$ is the yield moment, which represents if the response is plastic or elastic (depending whether $M$ is less that $M_y$).

I have supposed the force $Y_3$ is loaded by the step-wise loading function $f$. As $f$ is not differentiable, I manually defined its 'derivative' as $g$. So I've differentiated the equation 5a) to include $g$ (hidden in each $V_{Yi}$).

For the Heaviside function $H$ I used an approximation $H(x,n) \approx \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{\pi} \arctan (n*x)$. For higher defined n it is sufficient approximation.

My code is (including all initial and boudary conditions - the length of one segment $l$ is 1 - I am assuming to have two only segments of the total length $2*l$. Also discretization for the curvature $\kappa $ as $\kappa_i \approx \dfrac{\theta_i - \theta_{i-1}}{l}$ is used.

```
n := 10000; 
H[x_, n_] := (1/2) + (1/Pi) ArcTan[n*x];
My := 1; (*yield bending moment*)
 (*approximation of the Heaviside step function*)
EI := 0.5; (*Young modullus*)
l := 1; (*length of one segment*)
tlimit := 1; (*for the definition of the loading function*)
Alpha1 := 30; (*coefficient*)
f[t_] := Piecewise[{{-t, t <= tlimit}, {-tlimit, 
     t <= tlimit + 5}, {t - tlimit - 6, 
     t <= tlimit + 6}}]; (*loading function*)
g[t_] := Piecewise[{{-1, t <= tlimit}, {0, t <= tlimit + 5}, {1, 
    t <= tlimit + 
      6}}]; (*derivative of loading function with definition of \
problematic points*)
eq = {x2[t] - x1[t] - l*Cos[theta1[t]] == 0,
  x3[t] - x2[t] - l*Cos[theta2[t]] == 0,
  y2[t] - y1[t] - l*Sin[theta1[t]] == 0,
  y3[t] - y2[t] - l*Sin[theta2[t]] == 
   0, (theta2'[t] - theta1'[t])*(1 - 
      H[(theta2'[t] - theta1'[t])*M2[t]/l, n])*(1 + 
      Tanh[Alpha1*H[1 - Abs[M2[t]/My], n]*(Abs[M2[t]/My] - 1)])*(EI/
      l) == M2'[t], 
  M1'[t] - M2'[t] == 
   g[t]*l*Cos[theta1[t]] - f[t]*l*Sin[theta1[t]]*theta1'[t],
  M2'[t] - M3'[t] == 
   g[t]*l*Cos[theta2[t]] - f[t]*l*Sin[theta2[t]]*theta2'[t],
  theta1[0] == 0,
  theta2[0] == 0,
  M1[0] == 0,
  M2[0] == 0,
  M3[0] == 0,
  y1[0] == 0,
  y2[0] == 0,
  y3[0] == 0,
  x1[0] == 0,
  x2[0] == l,
  x3[0] == 2*l,
  x1[t] == 0,
  y1[t] == 0,
  M3[t] == 0,
  theta1[t] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[eq, {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3}, {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[Evaluate[x3[t]  /. sol], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Unforunately, the code is not working. The error message is Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function \
within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both \
values and derivatives of the functions.

Please, can somebody help me??? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: There appear to be only four equations (apart from initial conditions) involving `{x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3}`, so they cannot be determined.

Comment: But If I include in sol = NDSolve[
  eq, {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, M1, M2, M3, theta1, theta2}, {t, 0, 
   100}] all variables it does not help to get a solution (again the same error message)?

Comment: We have 11 dependent variables **{x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, theta1, theta2, M1, M2, M3}** and we need 11 conditions. Actually we have 7.